# Nilpotent matrix in $\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We can prove that $A \in \mathbb C^{n,n}$ is nilpotent ($\exists m\ A^m=0$) if $p_A(t)=t^n$, where $p_A$ is the characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$.

What if $A \in R^{n,n}$?

Proof that $p_A(t)=t^n \ \Rightarrow \ \exists m\ A^m=0$ is not hard.

If $p_A(t)=t^n$, then Jordan's decomposition of matrix $A$ looks like this:

$J=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & z_1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & z_2 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots& \dots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & \dots & z_{n-1}\\
0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & \dots & 0
\end{bmatrix}$,

where $z_i$ is equal to $0$ or $1$.

It is easy to see that $\exists m \ J^m=0$, and that $J$ is the Jordan decomposition of $A:$

$A=SJS^{-1}.$

So $\exists m \ A^m=0$.

How to prove that, if $A$ is nilpotent, then its characteristic polymonial is equal to $t^n$?

Comment: If $A\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ then we also have $A\in\Bbb C^{n\times n}$, and $A$ is nilpotent, so by the first line of your question, we know that $p_A(t)=t^n$.

Comment: Do you know the Cayley–Hamilton theorem? Then it is very easy to see that this is the case. However, since $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \subset \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a subspace it is automatically the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your real matrix and view it as a complex matrix.  Does the characteristic polynomial change?  No, because it is given by the same determinant.  Also of course whether $A^m = 0$ does not depend on whether $A$ is viewed as a real or complex matrix.

Doesn't that succeed in reducing the real case to the already known complex case?

**Added**: For some material on how invariant subspaces behave under scalar extension (the present question is an easy case of that), see $\S$9 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/invariant_subspaces.pdf).

Comment: I thought that if matrix $A\in R^{n,n}$, then we look only at real eigenvalues. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: If you want to work over $\mathbb{R}$ without also working over $\mathbb{C}$, your perspective on the characteristic polynomial should be that it could potentially factor into both into linear factors (which give -- real! -- eigenvalues) and irreducible quadratic factors (e.g. $t^2+1$), so it carries more information than just the eigenvalues and their multiplicities.  You are assuming that the characteristic polynomial is $t^n$, so there are no irreducible quadratic factors.  Still the simplest way to see that this implies nilpotence is by going up to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: If you are determined to stick to $\mathbb{R}$ at all points, you could still solve the problem by applying the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, which says that $p_A(A) = 0$ and holds over any field of scalars.  But if you know about complex scalars at all -- as you clearly do, since you began your question by mentioning the complex case -- then the answer I gave seems much easier.